# how to add two columns as result in single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below queries

```
select a.emp_id,a.AUTH_TYPE,b.NTE_TX as des1
  from table  a inner join NOTES b on b.TBL_ROW_ID=a.emp_id
 where a.emp_id=56 and REF_NTE_TYP_ID=27
```

**Output 1**

[image]

```
select a.emp_id,a.AUTH_TYPE,b.NTE_TX as des2
  from table  a inner join NOTES b on b.TBL_ROW_ID=a.emp_id
 where a.emp_id=56 and REF_NTE_TYP_ID=28
```

**Output 2**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

please help any one.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `Aggregation(MAX)` will help you to get your expected output.

Try this:

```
select a.emp_id,a.AUTH_TYPE
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN REF_NTE_TYP_ID=27 THEN b.NTE_TX END) as des1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN REF_NTE_TYP_ID=28 THEN b.NTE_TX END) as des2
  from table  a inner join NOTES b on b.TBL_ROW_ID=a.emp_id
where a.emp_id=56 and REF_NTE_TYP_ID IN(27,28)
GROUP BY a.emp_id,a.AUTH_TYPE
```

Comment: while executing below query getting below error
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

Comment: please reply @dineshdb

Comment: @RutherA, are you running this query only or you are running something else with this?

Answer (score 0):

If `TBL_ROW_ID, REF_NTE_TYP_ID` is unique in your table `NOTES`you can also use subqueries:

```sql
select a.emp_id,a.AUTH_TYPE
     , (SELECT b.NTE_TX 
          FROM NOTES b 
         WHERE b.TBL_ROW_ID=a.emp_id
           AND REF_NTE_TYP_ID=27) as des1
     , (SELECT b.NTE_TX 
          FROM NOTES b 
         WHERE b.TBL_ROW_ID=a.emp_id
           AND REF_NTE_TYP_ID=28) as des2
  from table a
 where a.emp_id=56
```

If you have multiple text-entries you might want to concatenate these entries to just print one long text (replace the 2 occurences of `SELECT b.NTE_TX` with the following):

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(b.NTE_TX, CHR(10)).EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY b.NTE_TX).GetClobVal(),CHR(10))
```

I used `CHR(10)` as text delimiter, just replace it with any other string you want. And you might also want some other `ORDER BY`condition.

Comment: while executing below query getting below error
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

Comment: Okay if column `NTE_TX` is of datatype `LONG` your task is not possible as oracle allows only one column to be of type `LONG`. If you can, migrate that column to a `CLOB` using [Migrating Columns from LONGs to LOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm).

Comment: ITS WORKING BUT MY 
TBL_ROW_ID, REF_NTE_TYP_ID COLUMNS  ARE NOT  unique 
GETTING BELOW ERROR
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Then the question is, how you want to deal with multiple entries per key `TBL_ROW_ID, REF_NTE_TYP_ID`. One solution is to concatenate the entries using `LISTAGG`-aggregate function.

Comment: please let me know the query

Answer (score 0):

```
With Q1 As (
    select 56 emp_id, 'diple' auth_type 
),
Q2 As (
    Select 'text2' Des2,27 ref_nte_type_id, 56 row_id 
    Union All
    Select 'text1' Des2,28 ref_nte_type_id, 56 row_id 
)

Select Q1.*,Q2.Des2,Q3.Des2 Des1 
    From Q1 
    Inner Join Q2 
    On Q1.Emp_Id=Q2.Row_Id
    And Q2.Ref_Nte_Type_Id=27
    Inner Join Q2 Q3
    On Q1.Emp_Id=Q3.Row_Id
    And Q3.Ref_Nte_Type_Id=28
```